# To-Many relationship (CoreData) with counters

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a project with two entities - Ingredients and Dishes, with many to many relationships.
In every dish I keep a relationship to the ingredients. I am trying to have a counter for the right quantity for each ingredient for every dish (for example, dish "Omlet" should have "Egg" with property "2" and "Milk" with property "1"....). 
I am struggling with the right way to model the counter and how to define it, any help there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third entity to model this. First, remove your to-many relationship. Then create a new entity called `IngredientQuantity` (or whatever you like) and add a property amount of type integer. Now, add two to-one relationships to `IngredientQuantity`. The first one points to your Dish entity and the second one to your Ingredient entity.

Comment: You probably meant "to-one" relationship, not "one-to-one". Because the inverse relationships from Dish and Ingredient to IngredientQuantity would probably be "to-many" relationships. - Apart from that a good solution.